# The parameter order of function for ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Suppose I have a map function like below:

```
let rec map f xs = match xs with
[] -> []
| hd :: tl -> f hd :: (map f tl)
```

I got some errors when I change the signature of map to `let rec map xs f`,
Could anyone pinpoint which knowledge I am lacking and explains why?

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem if you change the definition *and the recursive call*.

```
# let rec map xs f = match xs with
  [] -> []
  | hd :: tl -> f hd :: (map tl f);;
val map : 'a list -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b list = <fun>
# map [3; 5; 7] ((+) 1);;
- : int list = [4; 6; 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to switch the `xs` with the `f`

the only thing you have to make sure to change is the the order on line 3 where you have `(map f tl)` to `(map tl f)`